# How to pass parameters of custom class object from XAML to C# Constructor in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a `CarouselView` which has an array of `ContentView`s. Each `ContentView.xaml.cs` has a constructor that initializes values passed from the parent page that is containing the `CarouselView`.

I know how to pass basic generic types as parameters such as int, double, string, etc. But how can I pass parameters of a custom class object from XAML to the constructor in C# code?

**Here is my XAML markup for parent page containing the `CarouselView`:**

```xml
<CarouselView x:Name="carouselView" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Loop="False">
    <CarouselView.ItemsSource>
        <x:Array Type="{x:Type ContentView}">
            <ContentView>
                <carouselViews:CompanyView /> // This calls default parameterless constructor
            </ContentView>
            <ContentView>
                <carouselViews:DetailView />
            </ContentView>
            <ContentView>
                <carouselViews:LocationView />
            </ContentView>
        </x:Array>
    </CarouselView.ItemsSource>
    <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentView Content="{Binding .}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselView>
```

**Here is the constructor of the code behind of the page containing `CarouselView`:**

```cs
public partial class ParentPage : ContentPage
{
    CompanyDetailPageViewModel CompanyDetailPageVM;
    List<CompanyTabView> CompanyTabViews = new List<CompanyTabView>();

    public CompanyDetailPage(Models.Company.Company companyItem) // I want to pass this companyItem object to the CompanyView Constructor
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**Here is the constructor of one of the `ContentView` in the `CarouselView`:**

```cs
public partial class CompanyView : ContentView
{
    public CompanyTabView(Models.Company companyItem)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Debug.WriteLine($"Company Name: {companyItem}");
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume that cannot be done in xaml, but could have workaround from code behind, like create a `List<ContentView>()` and bind to your carousel view, and add the instance with data like `new CompanyTabView(myCompanyItem)` into the list.

Comment: ItemsSource should be data, not view. Use a [DataTemplateSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.datatemplateselector?view=xamarin-forms) to select a view based on content. For CarouselView see [Choose an EmptyViewTemplate at runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/emptyview#choose-an-emptyviewtemplate-at-runtime).

Comment: @Benl, I am not talking about `ItemsSource`, It is working fine when Views are containing parameterless constructor. The problem is arising when having parameterized constructor in `View.xaml.cs`.

Comment: @JunedKhanMomin I recommend to create [Xamarin.Forms Bindable Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties) for your customcontrol, not using parameter in constructor.